# Magento 2 : Disabling Cache For Specific Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, cache

In my module, I am adding small snippet to every page on site with layout file, that I have attached below. The thing is, I would like to disable caching for my module. How do I do that without disabling FPC for whole page? Using `cacheable="false"` will make whole page non-cached. So this option won't work for me.

I have already tried following:

1. controlling cache through the constructor, my block derives from `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` and setting up cache like this : `$this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => null));` didn't work.
2. adding parameters to my block in layout file:

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
           <body>
               <referenceContainer name="content">
                   <block class="Something\Something\Block\SnippetBlock" name="snippetblock" template="snippetblock.phtml"> 
                    <arguments>
                                       <argument name="cache_lifetime" xsi:type="null">null</argument>
                             </arguments>
               </block>
               </referenceContainer>
           </body>
   ```
3. overwriting `getCacheLifetime()` method to return null. 
   And this is my layout file that I am using now:

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Something\Something\Block\SnippetBlock" name="snippetblock" template="snippetblock.phtml" />
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
   ```

I will gladly listen to any suggestion.

Comment: Have you try to caching magento, and then check?

Comment: Each time I am altering my code I am doing bin/magento cache:clean just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento2, You have to render the content via JS (Ajax).
Check how the mini-cart & login/logout section has been implemented.

**Note**: There is no concept like hole-punching like in Magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for your construct method.

```
public function _construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
) {
    $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    $this->customerSession = $session;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me unfortunately. 
Maybe I am testing it in wrong way:
1 when page cache is disabled i can modify manually code of my snippet refresh page and see the changes.
2 when page cache is enabled I am modyfing code refresh page but changes do not appear until I flush the cache.

I would expect that if one of above methods for disabling cache would work the effect would be the same as in point 1.